# Jquery Mobile loses listview styles on refresh

Tags: jquery, listview, mobile, styles, refresh

I've spent hours trying to get to the bottom of this.I'm using Jquery mobile to output a list of events.

the page loads and the list view is operating as normal. I can traverse around my app without any issues, however when I  refresh the page as many others have found the JM styles  get dropped. I've tried most if not all of the solutions offered on the forum which probably means Im not implementing the suggestion correctly or they're nt relevant to my code.

I have tried the refresh option   "$("#vg_list").listview("refresh");" to no avail 
and  from the jquery documentation it looks like this is only relative  when using  append.

I've also tried  the alternatives to the document.ready function with no success. 
Here is my code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div id="mygatherings"
    data-theme="a"
    data-role="page"
           data-title="View Source:mygatherings">
    <!-- header: My Gatherings  start -->
            <div data-role="header"
        data-theme="a"
        data-position="fixed"
        data-id="vs_header">

        <h1>My Gatherings</h1>
        <a href="#home"
            data-icon="home"
            data-iconpos="notext"
                            data-transition="slide"
            >Home</a>
        <a href="#"
            data-icon="back"
            data-iconpos="notext"
                            data-rel="back"
                            data-transition="slide"
            >back</a>
            </div><!-- My Gatherings : create end --> 

            <!-- Content:My Gatherings start -->


             <div id="vg" data-role="listview" ></div>

$(document).ready(function(){

 $.getJSON("fetch.php", function(data) {

   var output='<ul  data-role="listview">';
   $.each(data.result,function(key,val){

     output+='<li>';
       output+='<h3>Event Name:' + val.name + '</h3>'; 
       output+='<p>Location:' + val.location + '</p>'; 
       output+='<il>Contact:'+ val.email + '</li>'; 
       output+='</li>';

            });
       output+='</ul>';

       $('#vg').html(output);


     });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out after many hours of banging my head against the wall.Check out the code below.

```
 $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#mygatherings', function(){ 
                update();

   });
function update(){      
 $.getJSON("fetch.php", function(data) {

   var output='<ul  data-role="listview">';
   $.each(data.result,function(key,val){

     output+='<li>';
       output+='<h3>Event Name:' + val.name + '</h3>'; 
       output+='<p>Location:' + val.location + '</p>'; 
       output+='<il>Contact:'+ val.email + '</li>'; 
       output+='</li>';
       output+='</ul>'; 
    });

  $('#vg').html(output);
  $("#vg").listview("refresh");

 });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
$.getJSON("fetch.php", function(data) {

   var output='<ul  data-role="listview">';
   $.each(data.result,function(key,val){

     output+='<li>';
       output+='<h3>Event Name:' + val.name + '</h3>'; 
       output+='<p>Location:' + val.location + '</p>'; 
       output+='<il>Contact:'+ val.email + '</li>'; 
       output+='</li>';

            });
       output+='</ul>';

       $('#vg').html(output);


     }).done(function(){
     $("#listviewid").listview().listview("refresh"); 
         });
```